# control algorithm simulation using transfer function of plant model in simulink

Tags: simulink

I want to implement inverter whose output voltage, frequency and phase can be varied according to need. For simulating control algorithm, I would like to use transfer function of plant(in my case it's an inverter). Then for control, i will use PID controller. But, i am not getting transfer function for my plant model. Can any one suggest any way?

[https://www.google.co.in/search?q=full+bridge+inverter&espv=2&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIx7H8xdPSxwIV0sWOCh1TJQea&biw=1280&bih=923#imgrc=rO68uFrnMtt5aM%3A](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=full%20bridge%20inverter&espv=2&es_sm=93&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIx7H8xdPSxwIV0sWOCh1TJQea&biw=1280&bih=923#imgrc=rO68uFrnMtt5aM%3A)

Comment: can some one please reply?

Comment: Do you have a plant model? Can you put the equations in your question?

Comment: plant is full bridge inverter consisting of 4 IGBT switches, which takes 100V DC as input and gives AC output using LC filter across C.